# Need help in calculation 1+2+3+4...+n?

Tags: java, addition, calculation

So I'm assigned to write a program, which asks a number (n) and then makes a addition like this: 1+2+3+4...+n and prints the addition

I keep getting wrong numbers though and can't figure out what is wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LukusarjanSumma {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int addition = 0;
        System.out.println("Where to?");
        int n = Integer.valueOf(reader.nextLine());
        while (addition <= n){
            addition += addition;
            addition ++;
        } System.out.println("Total is " + addition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you increment `addition` by both itself and 1? You're effectively writing `addition = 2 * addition + 1;`.

Comment: http://www.jepspectro.com/htmDoc/Little%20Gauss%20formula.htm

Comment: Actual for this primitive level of questions, I'd like to suggest that people should try to simulate their program with pencil and paper (if they are seemingly unable to use a debugger). It seems the user took little to no effort trying to solve the problem before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to differenciate

- the `additition` that sums up all
- a `counter` that values the increasing index : `1,2,3...n`

  ```
  int addition = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  System.out.println("Where to?");
  int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
  while (counter <= n) {
      addition += counter;
      counter++;
  }
  System.out.println("Total is " + addition);
  ```

But the easier would be to use a for loop, this is more logical

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    addition += i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a more modern solution, you could use something along the lines of this:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt("10");
        int sum = IntStream.range(0, n).reduce(n, (a, b) -> a  + b);
        System.out.println("Total is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Obviously in my example it doesn't take any input from the CLI, it's just a fixed value, but I'm certain you get the idea. You may be asking why I like solution over the likes of a more traditional for loop purely because of how small & concise it is, I just generally find it much easier to read & maintain.

Not to mention that a solution like this introduces you to some concepts related to functional programming, such as immutability. While cools guys like [Eric Elliott](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0) may do a lot of tutorials in JavaScript, the principles are transferable to practically any language! :)

### A little bit of theory

While functional programming rocks, **the precise example I've provided may not be the most appropriate if your core target is performance**. In this case, *it is* better to use a more traditional solution, but given it's such a primitive application/piece of code, I think it's fine.

From a computational complexity perspective, from a speed & branching perspective, it's roughly the same as a traditional solution, *however*, just by using a stream, never mind creating the range, it's likely using more memory than a simple for loop. **But** you could also argue that the compiler would do such a great job that it may actually implement this as a traditional for loop.

With my solution, it does 9 iterations, if you were to use a for loop like the one @azro provided, then the code would result in 10 iterations, so that's also something to think about I guess! :)

---

### Edit

I should note that this solution will work with Java 8+.

Comment: Appreciate your time to answer such an idiomatic question as mine! But since I've only been familiar with Java for like 4 hours, that goes way over the top right now (:D), but will definitely keep your comment in mind for future purposes!

Comment: @pakkis26 I assumed that this was the case, hence why I decided to include a little bit of theory, not so much that it would blow your mind or anything. If you need help learning, feel free to give me a message! :)

Comment: @pakkis26 It may also be worth looking into the likes of [lambda expressions](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-lambda-expressions-tips).

Answer (score 0):

You need two variables, one for the sum and the other for the current number to be added:

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Where to?");
    int n = Integer.valueOf(reader.nextLine());
    while (i <= n){
        sum += i;
        i++;
    } System.out.println("Total is " + sum);
```